# Cant connect to database using docker compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm struggling to find why I cannot connect my Spring Boot app to a Mysql database.
This is what I've put inside the `properties file`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:127.0.0.1}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/app1
spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USER:root}
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:mypassword}
```

And this is the docker compose

```
 services:

  data-base:
    image: mysql:8.0-oracle
    volumes:
      - ./init-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password000
    networks:
      my-network:
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

  back-end:
    build:
      context: my_backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: data-base
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password000
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
    networks:
      my-network:
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - data-base
      
           
  front-end:
    build:
      context: my_frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    networks:
      my-network:
    depends_on:
      - back-end
        
networks:
  my-network:
```

The mysql container is running. Sometime it connected, after it caught some exceptions a few times, I dont know how it connected because I haven't changed anything, but it wont connect anymore.
Its not that the database doesnt exist, Im creating it inside the script it is "connection refused"
`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final] Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: Can you provide a complete error stack trace? Thanks !

Comment: I think the problem is that the 'back-end' starts before the 'data-base' finishes, but I dont know why is that since I've metioned 'depends_on', and it restarts untill the data-base finishes then works

Comment: What version of docker-compose do you use?

Comment: I'm using latest version

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working code. You can use this code for your testing:

```
version: '2'
services:

  mysqldb:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: silicon
      MYSQL_USER: maninder
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: maninder
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - kafka-stack-network

networks:
  kafka-stack-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      jdbc:
        batch_size: 1000
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/silicon
    username: maninder
    password: maninder
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```